# How to remove timestamp from date field in sharepoint designer workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2013;
Simply I have a loop running that should exit when DueDate (Date field) is greater than TodayToday (Date field). Both these dates are variables set inside the workflow itself. It doesn't seem to end the loop (when I want) and I am confident this is due to the timestamp.

[image: Workflow log set to test:]

In the picture above you can see DueDate (1) is set to 15/09/2016 08:28:44 and TodayToday (2) changes to 15/09/2016 00:00:00 on the 15th but the DueDate is still greater than the TodayToday date (based on the timestamp) and therefore will not exit the loop.

Does anyone have a solution around this? I know if I remove the timestamps from the date fields this will work but I am not sure how to do this inside the sharepoint designer workflow (where the variables are set).

Answer (score 1):

Inside your workflow store Today's Date in a string variable and do the same with DueDate. Then with the time function inside workflow set the time to 00:00 and then compare the two variables.

[image: Example of stripping time from date]

Comment: If I answered your question correctly can you please mark it checked and vote for me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, casting into string fields does work, however you cannot perform compares on the string fields.  So you cannot test if Today>DateField.